# Grease Pencil-Preceding frame visible in next frame(non onion skin)-turn off please

Tags: grease-pencil, timeline

Simply, Draw something on frame 1 and then I go to frame 2 but the contents of frame 1 are still visible until I start drawing on frame 2(contents of frame1 then disappear from view until I return to frame 1)...
 I would prefer that I get a completely empty frame as I advance through the timeline.
Is that possible?

I guess I should be clear on if this is normal behavior or if its just a bug on my end? When draw on frame 1 and then advance forward to frame 2 is the contents of frame 1 still visible on your view port?

Answer (score 1):

This is defacto standard in 2D-animation. This behavior makes easy to draw on twos, threes, ets. without adding additional keyframes. (When you draw every second frame it is called "drawing on twos", every third - "drawing on threes" and so on.) Timeline looks clear and ones, twos and threes easy to recognize and manipulate with them.

[Know more why using twos is important in 9th Principle of Animation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BarOk2p38LQ&index=9&list=PL-bOh8btec4CXd2ya1NmSKpi92U_l6ZJd)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the default behavior of grease pencil. You can enable to the next frame still the same drawing before, but normaly is the drawing appear just to give a position and disapear when you start draw.